# Why does post request only works the first time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web scraper with python, I made it with selenium but it is really slow.Then i saw that i could speed up the project because of a button that make a post request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://vidtome.host/tnoz00am9j8p"

myobj = {
    'op': 'download1',
    'code':'tnoz00am9j8p',
    'hash': 'the hash',
    'imhuman': 'Proceed to video'
}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
print(x.text)
```

That's the code and it works but only for the first time.
When I started it the first time it doesn't show any error and it printed me out the page with the right changes, but when i started it later it gave me no error but it printed me out the page with no changes like it doesn't do anything.
How can it be possible?

Comment: Normal page? New page? What URL are we seeking?

Comment: Need more details and clarity.

Comment: The [link](http://vidtome.host/tnoz00am9j8p) that you provided has a human check system which won't allow you to view website until you solve the check. Hence you get the error.

Comment: So i can only use selenium, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests are faster, but you cannot extract dynamically rendered content. However this is probably not the issue.

Problem is that you do not have access to the website.
If it is a basic human checking system, you could try to add user agent to your request

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.68',
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

If this will not work, I would recommend looking into the data that you are passing. Maybe it is validating through it and it contains expired values or something.